# How can I create a search bar with a ListView on Mono for Android?

Tags: c#, filter, xamarin.android, searchbar

I have to make a search bar, but I want to know how to filter the list while you are typing something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Search Widget or a SearchView, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html